# use multinomial theorem to show that $\sum\limits_{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=n} \frac{n! \cdot (-1)^{n_1+n_2}}{n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!}=0$

Tags: discrete-mathematics

use multinomial theorem to show that

$$\sum\limits_{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=n} \frac{n! \cdot  (-1)^{n_1+n_2}}{n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!}=0$$

where the summation extends over all non-negative solutions of $n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4 = n$

I have zero idea what to do, any tips? Also this is the first time I see this way of using sigma notation. So actually I don't quite get the question.

Comment: Start with $\,n=0.\,$ What is $\,0!\,$ and what is $\,n_1,n_2,n_3,n_4?$

Comment: should i use proof by induction? in the question it says use multinomial theorem also I forgot to write the -1^(n1+n2) part

Comment: @fatih Do you mean $$\sum_{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=n} \frac{n! \cdot  (-1)^{n_1+n_2}}{n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!}=0?$$

Comment: yes that is the correct form of the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** The multinomial theorem states that

$$(x_1+x_2+\ldots+x_k)^n\,=\sum_{n_1+\ldots+n_k=n}{n\choose n_1,\ldots,n_k}\,\cdot\, x_1^{n_1}\cdot x_2^{n_2}\cdots x_k^{n_k}$$

We can transform your expression:

$$\sum\limits_{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=n} \frac{n! \cdot  (-1)^{n_1+n_2}}{n_1!n_2!n_3!n_4!}=\sum\limits_{n_1+n_2+n_3+n_4=n} {n\choose n_1,\ldots,n_4}\cdot (-1)^{n_1}\cdot (-1)^{n_2}\cdot \color{red}1, $$

with $\color{red}1=1^{n_3}\cdot 1^{n_4}$